# Finalize() Method of Shopware 6 Payment Plugin Refuses To Run

Tags: shopware, shopware6, shopware6-app

I am implementing the Shopware 6 Asynchronous payment method following the guide  [Payment Plugin Guide](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/checkout/payment/add-payment-plugin#asynchronous-example).

The `pay(AsyncPaymentTransactionStruct $transaction, RequestDataBag $dataBag, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext)` method works well and redirects properly to my payment processor.

My return URL works fine too and returns to `http://localhost/account`, on return, I expected the `finalize(AsyncPaymentTransactionStruct $transaction, Request $request, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext)` method to run but nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong, I can as well implement my own solution but I would like to get this to work.

Here is my code

```php
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace PaystackShopware6Plugin\Service;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use UIPaymentShopware6Plugin\Service\PaymentLink;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Shopware\Core\System\SalesChannel\SalesChannelContext;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\Validation\DataBag\RequestDataBag;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\Cart\AsyncPaymentTransactionStruct;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\Exception\AsyncPaymentProcessException;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\Exception\CustomerCanceledAsyncPaymentException;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\Aggregate\OrderTransaction\OrderTransactionStateHandler;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\Cart\PaymentHandler\AsynchronousPaymentHandlerInterface;

class PayUI implements AsynchronousPaymentHandlerInterface
{
    private OrderTransactionStateHandler $transactionStateHandler;
    private PaymentLink $paymentLink;

    public function __construct(OrderTransactionStateHandler $transactionStateHandler, PaymentLink $paymentLink) {
        $this->transactionStateHandler = $transactionStateHandler;
        $this->paymentLink = $paymentLink;
    }

    /**
     * @throws AsyncPaymentProcessException
     */
    public function pay(AsyncPaymentTransactionStruct $transaction, RequestDataBag $dataBag, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): RedirectResponse
    {
        // Method that sends the return URL to the external gateway and gets a redirect URL back
        try {
/**the getPaymentLink(param) function returns a 'payment link' and accepts a parameter (param) which tells the payment processor which link to redirect the user to after a successful or failed transaction

*/
            $redirectUrl = $this->paymentLink->getPaymentLink('localhost/account');//$this->sendReturnUrlToExternalGateway(

$transaction->getReturnUrl());
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new AsyncPaymentProcessException(
                $transaction->getOrderTransaction()->getId(),
                'An error occurred during the communication with external payment gateway' . PHP_EOL . $e->getMessage()
            );
        }

        // Redirect to external gateway
        return new RedirectResponse($redirectUrl);
    }

    /**
     * @throws CustomerCanceledAsyncPaymentException
     */
    public function finalize(AsyncPaymentTransactionStruct $transaction, Request $request, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext): void
    {

        
        $transactionId = $transaction->getOrderTransaction()->getId();

        // Example check if the user cancelled. Might differ for each payment provider
        if ($request->query->getBoolean('cancel')) {
            throw new CustomerCanceledAsyncPaymentException(
                $transactionId,
                'Customer canceled the payment on the PayPal page'
            );
        }

        // Example check for the actual status of the payment. Might differ for each payment provider
        $paymentState = $request->query->getAlpha('status');

        $context = $salesChannelContext->getContext();
        if ($paymentState === 'completed') {
            // Payment completed, set transaction status to "paid"
            $this->transactionStateHandler->paid($transaction->getOrderTransaction()->getId(), $context);
        } else {
            // Payment not completed, set transaction status to "open"
            $this->transactionStateHandler->reopen($transaction->getOrderTransaction()->getId(), $context);
        }
    }

    private function sendReturnUrlToExternalGateway(string $getReturnUrl): string
    {
        $paymentProviderUrl = '';
        // Do some API Call to your payment provider
        return $paymentProviderUrl;
    }
}
```

Comment: In your payment processor you forward back to the `returnUrl` you get in the `AsyncPaymentTransactionStruct` right? And that URL again forwards you to `/account`? and you don't hard coded forwarding back directly to `http://localhost/account` in your processor?

Comment: @j_elfering the `pay(AsyncPaymentTransactionStruct $transaction, RequestDataBag $dataBag, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext)` function redirects to the payment processor and after processing the payment processor redirects to the store URL @ **localhost\account**. the `finalize(AsyncPaymentTransactionStruct $transaction, Request $request, SalesChannelContext $salesChannelContext)` function does not run. I don't know how the `sendReturnUrlToExternalGateway(string $getReturnUrl)` is intended to work. I was just taking the functions one after the other.

Comment: @j_elfering, I have updated my question with my codes so I can 'practically' understand your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly redirect to `shopUrl/account` from your payment processor, as shopware needs to be aware that the payment on your side of things completed and needs to call the `finalize()` method of the payment handler. Therefore your payment processor should rather redirect to the `returnUrl` provided in the pay step, this is a callback url with the id of the current pending transaction, and when it is called it finish the payment by executing the finalize method of the payment handler and then redirecting the customer to the storefront.

So that means you probably need to pass the `returnUrl` you get in the `pay()` step forward to your payment processor, so that that processor can then redirect back to that callback url, when the transaction handling is finished on the processor side, so that shopware can also finish/finalize the transaction.

Refer to [the docs](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/resources/references/adr/checkout/2021-10-01-payment-flow#asynchronous-payment) for a overview of how the workflow is expected to be executed.

So my guess would be that the code you provided should be changed in the following way:
Instead of

```php
$redirectUrl = $this->paymentLink->getPaymentLink('localhost/account');
```

You should use:

```php
$redirectUrl = $this->paymentLink->getPaymentLink($transaction->getReturnUrl());
```